# Erro na extensão Go Coverage Viewer no vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, golang

Toda vez que abro o vscode recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Cannot activate the 'Go Coverage Viewer' extension because it depends on an unknown 'ms-vscode.go' extension.
```

Já tentei verificar a instalação da extensão mas não há nenhum problema com ela, o vscode foi instalado corretamente através do [site da plataforma](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A extensão funciona perfeitamente, mas fica aparecendo essa mensagem sempre que abro e não consigo resolver esse erro, fora que não tem nenhum comentário sobre isso nos fóruns.

Alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 1):

Descobri, o pacote que eu estava instalando era por um fornecedor chamado "default", verifiquei que existia de outro chamado "Søren"...

Resumindo, desinstalei o antigo e instalei o novo e o erro parou de exibir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Caso sua resposta seja a solução definitiva, você pode marcá-la como solução do post.